# What is the trace of the algebraic element?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $F=\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}$ and that $\alpha$ is the root of the irreducible polynomial $p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots + a_0$. I am told that the trace of $\alpha$ is $-a_{n-1}$, but I don't understand why.

I know that we have $\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}\cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/p(x)$, and that the norm is equal to the sum of the conjugates of $\alpha$, but how do I calculate this?

Comment: As a side note, remember that the *trace* is the sum of the conjugates, not the norm.

Comment: A more natural, general, and transparent definition of the trace of $\alpha$ from $L=K(\alpha)$ to $K$ for any field $K$ is the trace of the $K$-linear map $L \rightarrow L$ given as multiplication by $\alpha$. With respect to the obvious basis of powers of $\alpha$, this matrix is

$$ \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & -a_0 \\
1 & 0 & \ldots  & 0 & -a_1 \\
\ddots & &  & &  \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & -a_{n-1} \end{matrix} \right) $$

which has trace $-a_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Galois closure (the splitting field of $p(x)$), we know 
$$
p(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n (x-\alpha_i)
$$
where the $\alpha=\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are the conjugates of $\alpha$. Now multiply out this product and look at the coefficient of the degree $n-1$ term: it's the sum of all the conjugates.

EDIT: More explicitly, if we multiply out this product, we have 
$$
p(x)=x^n-(\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i)x^{n-1}+\cdots +(-1)^n\prod_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0.
$$
 Hence $Tr_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=-a_{n-1}$ and $N_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)=\prod_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=(-1)^na_0$.

Comment: For the trace as well as for the norm, you need to indicate precisely to what extension you refer to. I suppose it is here $\mathbf Q(\alpha)/\mathbf Q$.